# Hibernate fails only in batch

Tags: java, hibernate

I get uniqueness constraint errors only when I insert into a Sybase table using batching of multiple transactions.
When I do one at a time, its fine. Any ideas why?

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert collection: [Product.CustomerList#component[ProductId,ProductVersion]{ProductVersion=0, ProductId=XBN20140603}]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1183)
        at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:26)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:343)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: columns ProductId, ProductVersion, CustomerLevel are not unique
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
        at org.sqlite.DB.executeBatch(DB.java:236)
        at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeBatch(PrepStmt.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:34)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1146)
```

Comment: Could be possible that yo have duplicate items in the collection. When inserting one at a time, it overrides the existing value in the DB, thats why no error. Solution could be, use SET to store the array items or try to remove the duplication item manually.

Comment: I printed out SQL by batching 1 vs batching 8 - there is no difference in the insert statements - yet the batching 8 fails. And I take the same inserts and insert manually and no problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. who is setting the productId , version and the customerLevel?

Comment: Make sure they are not repeated in all the 8 objects, try to print it in the console or debug it.